# Running Coffeescript snippets directly in Aptana Studio 3

Tags: coffeescript, aptana

Right now I am playing around with CoffeeScript and I loved to see that Aptana now supports it natively. But I am unable to "Run" the Script directly in Aptana to get the results printed to the built-in console.

When i click `Ctrl+R` as described in the CoffeeScript Bundle I only get a git-help information printed in the console.

For Example

script.coffee

```
console.log "Hello Coffee"
```

When I run it through the terminal by typing

```
$coffee script.coffee
```

I get the result printed perfectly.
I can't find any documentation or hints for solving this problem.
Am I missing something ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is an open ticket [here](http://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/APSTUD-4965) and a brief discussion [here](http://github.com/aptana/coffeescript.ruble/issues/2).

If this is your issue (look at the console if you get this `'line 3: pre: command not found' error`), then a temporary solution I found is to edit `Aptana Rubles/coffeescript.ruble/commands/run.rb` (located in ~/Documents in a linux installation) and remove ' | pre' from line 11.

After that, restart Aptana or reload the Coffeescript bundle from Bundles View (right-click on it->reload), select the text (will work only if there is selected text) and press `Ctrl-R + 1`. You should now see a new html file with the 'Hello Coffee' in it.

Hope this helps.